# Clojure rounding to decimal places

Tags: clojure, decimal

I have strings which represents the decimal values,
ex: "0.010", "0.0100000" "00.01000"

I want to round them to specified format,
ex: #.##

In Java we have:

```java
public BigDecimal setScale(int newScale, RoundingMode roundingMode) {
    return setScale(newScale, roundingMode.oldMode);
}
```

What is the best approach to achieve this in Clojure rather than using interop?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use Clojure's `format` for this purpose. It should provide you a solution to your problem. Here are some examples and a reference:

```
user=> (format "%.2f" 0.010)
"0.01"
user=> (format "%.2f" 0.010000)
"0.01"
user=> (format "%.2f" 00.010000000)


user=> (doc format)
-------------------------
clojure.core/format
([fmt & args])
  Formats a string using java.lang.String.format, see java.util.Formatter for format
  string syntax
```

Comment: cl-format should be used instead of format - format is only a thin wrapper around the java.util.Formatter and because of that it does not handle the Clojure's BigInt for example. As of Clojure 1.3 if your number is too big for a long it will overflow in a BigInt, which is the Clojure implementation, instead of BigInteger, which is the Java implementation. As you might guess java.util.Formatter does not handle the Clojure implementation and throws exception.

Comment: doesn't round, just floors it.

Comment: The Java 8 [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#decimal) seem to indicate that it does round

Answer (score 23):

This is a slightly modified version of an example at [clojure-doc.org](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/language/functions.html):

```
(defn round2
  "Round a double to the given precision (number of significant digits)"
  [precision d]
  (let [factor (Math/pow 10 precision)]
    (/ (Math/round (* d factor)) factor)))
```

@number23_cn's answer is the right one for many cases.  However, a real rounding function with a precision argument may be useful if, for example, you want to display a sequence with every number rounded.  Then you can simply map `round2` over the sequence to format every number at once:

```
(map (partial round2 2) [0.001 10.123456 9.5556])
```

which returns

```
(0.0 10.12 9.56)
```

This is more useful for a longer sequence, of course.

---

Another option is to use [`cl-format`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.pprint/cl-format), which is a Clojure implementation of Common Lisp's `format`.  It's similar to Clojure's `format` (which is based on `java.util.Formatter`) but has a different syntax, and allows some fancier tricks.

```
(clojure.pprint/cl-format nil "~,2f" 23.456)
; => "23.46"
```

The `~{ ~}` directive allows processing sequences, as in the first example above:

```
(clojure.pprint/cl-format nil "~{ ~,2f~}" [0.001 10.123456 9.5556])
; => " 0.00 10.12 9.56"
```

`~{ ~}` expects to see a sequence as an argument, and will eat elements of the sequence one by one using whatever directives appear between `~{` and `~}`.

(The [chapter on `format`](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/a-few-format-recipes.html) from Peter Seibel's [*Practical Common Lisp*](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) is the best introduction to Common Lisp's `format`, and therefore to Clojure's `cl-format`, imo.  The [documentation on CL's `format`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_c.htm) in the usual source, the [Common Lisp Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/index.htm), can be difficult to use sometimes.  The [section on CL's `format`](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/project/ai-repository/ai/html/cltl/clm/node200.html#SECTION002633000000000000000) in [*Common Lisp The Language*](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/project/ai-repository/ai/html/cltl/clm/clm.html) is slightly better.)

Comment: The docstring on round2 function is incorrectly stating that the precision parameter is referring to the number if significant digits. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures

it should say "number of fractional digits"

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer recommends `format`, yet `format` does not round (as pointed out in one of the comments). The other answer (by Mars) will not work for `BigDecimal`s. To round `bigdec`s to a number of decimal places in Clojure the only solution I have found is to use Java interop:

```
(defn round [s]
  (fn [n]
    (assert (bigdec? n))
    (.setScale n s RoundingMode/HALF_EVEN)))

(def round4 (round 4))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the function `Double/ParseDouble` after using `format` on the decimal number will return a decimal rounded to the desired number of decimals described by using `format`. Like so:

```
user=> (Double/parseDouble (format "%.2f" 0.009) ) 
0.01
```

If the rounded number is needed for further calculations, parsing a Double is important. However, if outputting a rounded number is all that is needed, then the use of `format` is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to convert these strings to BigDecimal values at the very beginning. Any numeric literal like `0.0001` or any numeric value may be inferred to a double or a float and you may loose the precision for numbers having very big scales.

Second thing is you probably don't want to explicitly format it, just rescale to some nominal scale:

```clj
(defn round
  [n scale rm]
  (.setScale ^java.math.BigDecimal (bigdec n)
             (int scale)
             ^RoundingMode (if (instance? java.math.RoundingMode rm)
                             rm
                             (java.math.RoundingMode/valueOf
                              (str (if (ident? rm) (symbol rm) rm))))))

(round "12.345" 2 :UP)
12.35M

(round "12.345" 2 :DOWN)
12.34M

(round "12.345" 2 :HALF_UP)
12.35M

(round "12.3" 2 :HALF_EVEN)
12.30M
```

To print it without the `M` letter just use `str` or `.toPlainString`:

```clj
(str (round "0" 2 :HALF_EVEN))
"0.00"

(.toPlainString ^java.math.BigDecimal (round "1.2" 4 :UP))
"1.2000"
```

You can also see how I abstracted similar thing in the [Bankster library](https://github.com/randomseed-io/bankster) (for playing with currencies and money) – look for the `apply` protocol method:

https://github.com/randomseed-io/bankster/blob/main/src/io/randomseed/bankster/scale.clj