# What is the best way to round numbers in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, rounding

This is an easy one. But anyway, I think it is a good idea to have this question answered here for a faster, easier reference.

This operation:

```
(/ 3 2)
```

yields this:

```
3/2
```

I need one function to round up, which would yield 2 and another one to round down, which would yield 1.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can java interop (Math/(floor|ceil).  E.g.:

```
user=> (int (Math/floor (/ 3 2)))
1
user=> (int (Math/ceil (/ 3 2)))
2
```

Answer (score 39):

cast it to the desired type

```
(int 3/2) 
=> 1
(double 3/2)
=> 1.5
(float 3/2)
=> 1.5
```

then wrap that in a call to `Math.round` etc.

```
user> (Math/round (double 3/2))
2
user> (Math/floor (double 3/2))
1.0
user> (Math/ceil (double 3/2))
2.0
```

Comment: You also have the [numeric.tower](https://github.com/clojure/math.numeric-tower).

Answer (score 10):

You can round also using **with-precision** function

```
=> (with-precision 10 :rounding FLOOR (/ 1 3M))
0.3333333333M
=> (with-precision 10 :rounding CEILING (/ 1 3M))
0.3333333334M
```

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-precision

Answer (score 4):

Clojure version 1.11 added the new [clojure.math namespace](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.math-api.html) with rounding functions. So you no longer need explicit interop:

```clj
=> (require '[clojure.math :refer [ceil floor round]])
=> (ceil 3/2)
2.0
=> (floor 3/2)
1.0
=> (round 3/2)
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, which produces a pair of the floor and ceiling for non-negative numerator and positive denominator:

```
(fn [num den] (let [q (quot num den)
                    r (rem  num den)]
                [q (if (= 0 r) q (+ 1 q))])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help if anyone wants a "round to precision" function

```clj
(defn round
  "Rounds 'x' to 'places' decimal places"
  [places, x]
  (->> x
       bigdec
       (#(.setScale % places java.math.RoundingMode/HALF_UP))
       .doubleValue))
```

Sources:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4826827/5811761
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale-int-java.math.RoundingMode-
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html

Comment: Note that this answer is related to a question at https://stackoverflow.com/q/10751638/1455243.  The answers describe other methods.