# Clojure - round to decimal if needed

Tags: clojure, floating-point, rounding

First of all, this is **not** a duplicate of [clojure-rounding-to-decimal-places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751638/clojure-rounding-to-decimal-places).

This is almost the same question, but with a twist : I want to round the values to a *maximum* of N decimals, but not add them if they are not needed.

Examples for 4 decimals :

```
0.0 => 0.0
0.1 => 0.1
8.6667 => 8.6667
3.33333333 => 3.3333
4.66666666 => 4.6667
```

Comment: as mathematically 1.0 and 1.0000 are the same number, can I assume you are talking about how these numbers print?

Comment: Mars's answer to the question you linked to above allows you to do that (specifically see the `round2` function from his answer which operates on doubles rather than strings and will therefore introduce no extraneous zeros).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like we are primarily concerned here with crafting numbers to that when expressed in base ten and drawn to a screen they will be printed with the correct number of digits without having to pass that number of digits to everywhere they could be printed from. This is a bit of an assumption on my part so my apologies if I'm answering the wrong question.

```
user> (map (fn [x] {x (Double. (format "%.4f" x))})
                    [0.0 
                     0.1 
                     8.6667 
                     3.33333333 
                     4.66666666])
 ({0.0        0.0} 
  {0.1        0.1} 
  {8.6667     8.6667} 
  {3.33333333 3.3333} 
  {4.66666666 4.6667})
```

This uses format to ensure that they will be formatted correctly. You should save the string creation and parsing by solving this mathematically as well. If speed is critical it could be faster that way if you are very careful.