# Clojure - How to set the lower precision

Tags: clojure, precision, bigdecimal

I know that to set the precision for numbers in Clojure I should use `with-precision` function and I know that it works only with BigDecimal values.

```
(defn bar-triang [[a b] [c d] [e f]]
  (def cen [(/ (+ a c) 2.0) (/ (+ b d) 2.0)])
  (def g (get cen 0))
  (def h (get cen 1))
    [(with-precision 4 (+ (bigdec g) (/ (- e g) 3M)))
     (with-precision 4 (+ (bigdec h) (/ (- f h) 3M)))])

(bar-triang [4, 6], [12, 4], [10, 10])
=> [8.666666666666666 6.666666666666667]
```

Here, I've set the precision to 4, but REPL gives me the same number as before with more digits. Furthermore, I've coerced `g` and `h` to BigDecimal using `bigdec`, but problem remains the same. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: not regarding precision, but to declare local variable use `let` like `(let [a 3] ..)` - you effectevly declare `cen` `g` and `h` as global accessible vars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a bit of refactoring later:

1. using `let` instead of `def`
2. why produce `cen` vector when you only need `h` and `g`
3. using `_M` for the numeric literals
4. wrap the whole thing in `with-precision 4`
5. drop `bigdec` coercions (thx [/u/glts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/329063/glts))
6. this may not be the best variant but to my knowledge it produces you desired output
7. It might be a good time to apply/research automated testing with clojure

---

```
(defn bar-triang [[a b] [c d] [e f]]
  (with-precision 4
    (let [g (/ (+ a c) 2M)
          h (/ (+ b d) 2M)]
      [(+ g (/ (- e g) 3M))
       (+ h (/ (- f h) 3M))])))
#'user/bar-triang
user=> (bar-triang [4, 6], [12, 4], [10, 10])
[8.667M 6.667M]
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, it solved the described problem. But now I realise, that `with-precision` function count all digits in the number, while I wanted to limit only digits after floating point.

Comment: @GrigoriyYanushkovsky so you want to round it - this is usually the last step of a calculation (why would you calc with rounded values) therefor it's usually an operation within "string" context: see `clojure.core/format` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751638/clojure-rounding-to-decimal-places

Comment: @birdspider No, I want to round only the result. Thanks for help!