# In Clojure or Java, how can I efficiently check whether a number is equivalent to an integer after rounding to two fractional digits?

Tags: java, clojure

I basically need a function in Clojure like `rounds-to-int?` which does the equivalent of this:

- Take an arbitrary number (int, float or double)
- Round it to at most two decimals (i.e. `1.000001234 => 1.00`)
- Determine whether the digits after the decimal point are both zero

e.g.

```
(rounds-to-int? 1) => true
(rounds-to-int? 1.234) => false
(rounds-to-int? 1.01) => false
(rounds-to-int? -1.01) => false
(rounds-to-int? 1.001) => true
(rounds-to-int? -1.001) => true
(rounds-to-int? 1.005) => false
(rounds-to-int? 1.004) => true
```

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: The following statement needs clarification: "Determine whether the digits after the decimal point are both zero." Are we only checking 2 digits to the after the decimal point, or are we checking all digit points after decimal point? It seems like any number between -1 and 1 will potentially have more than 2 digits after the decimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with, and ended up using.

```
(defn rounds-to-int?
  [value]
  (let [rounded (.setScale (bigdec value) 2 java.math.RoundingMode/HALF_UP)]
    (== (int rounded) rounded)))
```

Answer (score 0):

With the understanding that imprecision is inherent in the datatypes mentioned (e.g., large floating-points can't even cover with integer precision, so if you fed a large `Long` this would return false):

```
boolean roundsToInt(Number num) {
  var fractional = num.doubleValue() - num.intValue();
  return Math.abs(fractional) < 0.01; // usual warning about exact representations in binary
}
```

Comment: This implementation seems to maybe produce the incorrect result for the final 2 test cases given in the answer, although it is not 100% clear why both of those cases should be `false`.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's borrow a Clojure implementation for a function that rounds to a specific precision. I slightly modified [this answer from another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25098576/4297413).

```clj
(defn round-to
  "Modified from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25098576/4297413"
  [precision d]
  (let [factor (Math/pow 10 (- precision))]
    (/ (Math/round (* d factor)) factor)))
```

Next we can implement our custom rounding logic that respects the case where the number is a small-magnitude fraction between -1 and 1. The trick is to use log10 in order to get the digit of the first non-zero digit, also known as the most significant digit. We can leverage our `round-to` function to round `x` according to our special rules.

```clj
(defn my-fancy-round
  [x]
  ;; log10 can "count" the number of digits from the decimal point to the most significant digit. 
  ;; A negative log10 indicates that the most significant digit is to the right of the decimal point (aka x is between 0 and 1).
  (let [precision (int (Math/log10 (Math/abs x)))]
    (round-to (min precision -2) x)))
```

Lastly, we write our `rounds-to-int?` that will round the number with our custom logic and check if the result is an integer.

```clj
(defn rounds-to-int?
  [x]
  (let [rounded (my-fancy-round x)]
    (= rounded (Math/floor rounded))))
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this fails the case `1.005` which should round up to `1.01` (I just added this to the examples in the question).

Answer (score -1):

Please see the function `rel=` [in the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#floating-point-number-comparison).  It does exactly what you want:

```
(is      (rel=   123450000   123456789 :digits 4 ))       ; .12345 * 10^9
(is (not (rel=   123450000   123456789 :digits 6 )))
(is      (rel= 0.123450000 0.123456789 :digits 4 ))       ; .12345 * 1
(is (not (rel= 0.123450000 0.123456789 :digits 6 )))

(is      (rel= 1 1.001 :tol 0.01 ))                       ; :tol value is absolute error
(is (not (rel= 1 1.001 :tol 0.0001 )))
```